# What is the most appropriate kind of hardware to run a Tor relay on?

Tags: relays, bandwidth, performance

In the purpose of setting up a Tor relay that makes good use of a fast FTTH connection, what computer will do the job most efficiently at the time of writing, provided the **following requirements** are met?

Requirements:

1. best **bandwidth usage / power consumption** ratio
2. **must** run Linux, any flavor of it but preferably GNU / free software (proprietary blobs *not* encouraged)
3. *low* budget, let's say less than 250 US dollars?

The real capacity of the Internet connection is not known, but possibly capped at more than 1 Gbit/s. Not all the bandwidth needs to be made use of, speed / power ratio takes precedence.

Single board computers (Odroid, Raspberry Pi...) seem to be the winners at first sight. However I would like to get answers based on the specifics of Tor reference implementation, which I have no clue about. Would it benefit more from higher CPU clock frequency? Multiple cores? Bigger RAM? **What does Tor need the most?**

I tried to identify some of the basics:

- **cryptographic routines** need:

  - fast CPU
  - is Tor optimized for specific instruction set (NEON, SSE, AVX...)?
  - is Tor optimized for several cores?
- **connection management** need:

  - Gigabit link
  - lots of memory (2GiB as a bare minimum?)
  - big CPU cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- Tor does not make much use of more than one core, **two cores** (or one hyperthreaded core) **per process is best**
- a maximum of two Tor processes may register from a single IP, so **a CPU with 4 cores is ideal**
- **64-bit** is best for cryptography
- **2 GiB** of system memory is a bare minimum

---

Whilst I can't back it up with much technical details, this is from what I learnt in the last couple of months reading stuff and playing around with relays on different kinds of hardware. For me **the Odroid C2 currently takes the prize** with high-capacity connections (say 100+ Mbps), provided it runs two Tor processes.

The pros:

- **very** low power consumption (compared to a server/desktop configuration)
- 1 Gbps link
- fast (2 GHz) 64-bit CPU
- 2 GiB of RAM

The cons:

- no support of the AES-NI instruction set, the only one that Tor/OpenSSL really needs

So far I've been able to squeeze 5-6 M**bytes** of pure Tor traffic (directory listings excluded) from it, still increasing.

Information on technical requirements and how to configure and maintain a high-throughput relay may be found on the [Tor Servers wiki](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/). A reference documentation about Tor specifics can be found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/or-talk@freehaven.net/msg14159.html) under *Machine Specs*, e.g. speaking about cores:

> Tor is currently not fully multithreaded, and tends not to benefit
>   beyond 2 cores per process. Even then, the benefit is still marginal
>   beyond just 1 core.

Comment: Do you say that a single Odroid C2 can deliver 5-6 Mbytes of traffic? That's pretty impressive. Do you run it with 1 or 2 Tor processes? And how is the CPU and memory load during that traffic?

Comment: Try https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-h2plus/

Answer (score 0):

I think the (new) **[ODROID-H2+](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-h2plus/)** board really fits well for these requirements. Since it comes with x86 architecture meaning you have AES-NI (new instruction) set for hardware acceleration. Which is really needed if you want to run a decent Tor relay/node.

Also you can install as many RAM memory (DIM slots) as you need, eg. 2 GB or 4GB, or 16GB or even more...